# Excel - function in a MEDIAN-function

Tags: excel, function, median

I want to use the command `MEDIAN` in Excel but I want to make the program so that it takes the value in a column from 1 to a row that depens on a calculation in a different column and row.

For example:

```
=MEDIAN(G1:G(L1))
```

where `L1` is a calculted value 
The calculated value in L1 will vary and therefore this procedure will repeat itself for many couple of times. Therefore, I don't want to write the number `(of G)` direct into the `MEDIAN`-function.

Please help me! :)

Comment: I don't follow your question, but you do know about the INDIRECT function?

Comment: Probably easier to use `Median(G1:Offset(G1,L1-1,0))` or `Median(G1:Index(G:G, L1))`

Comment: @chrisneilsen +1 for the INDEX option, which, being non-volatile, is much preferable to volatile INDIRECT/OFFSET set-ups. Suggest you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it corerctly you want to write a formula that calculate the median for a specific column, but you only want to calculate it from values in the range G1:X, where X is another cell in column G, which you calculate based on some criteria. If so then this would solve it:

```
=MEDIAN(G1:(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(X;7))))
```

Where X is your formula that calculates which row, i.e. cell is the last to be included in the column G.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It works! :D
Just curious what number 7 stands for?

Comment: ADDRESS allows you to reference a cell using row and column number, so the 7 represents column 7, i.e. the G-column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula.

```
=MEDIAN($G$1:(INDIRECT(ADDRESS($L$1,COLUMN($G$1)))))
```

[image]